# Android multi project test dependency setup breaks with Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0 in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0, android-gradle-3.0

I am trying to migrate from Android gradle plugin 2.3.3 to 3.0. I have a 2 projects set up where tests in ProjectB uses the test classes present in `src/test/java` from ProjectA. I utilizes the following setup to achieve this while using android gradle plugin 2.3.3 -

ProjectA `build.gradle` -

```
task myTestsJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: testClasses) {
   from sourceSets.test.output      
}

configurations {
  testArtifacts
}

artifacts {
   testArtifacts myTestsJar
}
```

ProjectB `build.gradle` -

```
dependencies {
  testCompile project(path: ':ProjectA', configuration: 'testArtifacts')
}
```

As you can see I am first trying to Jar all the test classes in ProjectA by using an artificat configuation and then later consuming that configuration in ProjectB. This was working as expected while using Android gradle pluign 2.3.3.

Now when migrating to AGP 3.0, my ProjectA `build.gradle` remains same though I have modified the projectB `build.gradle` to use `testImplementation` instead of `testCompile` like this -

```
dependencies {
      testImplementation project(path: ':ProjectA', configuration: 'testArtifacts')
}
```

This successfully compiles though while running any tests in ProjectB that utilizes test classes from ProjectA, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` for ProjectA test classes. Moreover this only happens while I am running tests in Android Studio using a Junit run configuration and no such `ClassNotFoundException` occurs when running tests through command line.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong while trying to get it work. So please help!

Answer (score 1):

Turned out it was something related to Gradle cache and I solved this by deleting my project's `.gradle` directory.